# Cannot to connect to sql server through PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have installed to a computer, MS SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition and created through Management Studio 17 an instance and a database. On another computer that runs IIS7, i enabled PHP extension through FastCGI and created an application.

In my application i try to run a php file with the following code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('IP_OF_SQL_SERVER_INSTALLATION', 'USER_OF_SQL_DB', 'PASSWORD_OF_DB_USER', 'PORT_USED_FOR_SQL_APP')
    or die('Error connecting to mysql: '.mysql_error());

?>
```

i wait for around 1 minute and then i get 500 - Internal server error. In SQL computer, i have enabled TCP/IP for my instance, i have opened ports 1433 (TCP) and 1434 (UDP) from windows firewall as inbound rules. Also i installed Management Studio 17 to another computer to the same network and when i try to connect from there, i get a connection. Any ideas on this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't use `mysql_connect()` to connect to MS SQL Server. Try PDO or `sqlsrv_connect()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: Do i have to install an extension for this to work?If yes, is it compatible with PHP 5.6.31?

Comment: Pretty sure you do, though I can't help you with that.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: Apparently if you use PDO you just have to enable extension `php_pdo_odbc` that is present in PHP by default.